# Unrecognized selector sent to instance with FIRAuth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting the following error

```
2017-02-07 23:50:44.987 Eat and Write[43621:3732723] -[UIViewController logOutAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa7a4c379c0
2017-02-07 23:50:44.991 Eat and Write[43621:3732723] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController logOutAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa7a4c379c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103beed4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010322f21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c5ef04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b74005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b73b88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000104ad28bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000104c58c38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000104c58f51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000104c57e4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104b40545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000104b41c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000104aee9ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001052db72d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001052d4463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b93761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b7898c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b77e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b77884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107f8ba6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000104ad0c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  Eat and Write                       0x00000001021e750f main + 111
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106d7568d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This code seems to be the problem

```
@IBAction func logOutAction(_ sender: Any) {

    try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()

    if FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser != nil { // <-- scheint zu buggen
        do {
            try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "AuthScreen", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Logging in and the other stuff from FIRAuth.auth() works just fine. I also can "jump" between Storyboards easily. I do not know where the problem lays.

EDIT:
I have the feeling that the error lays somewhere within the

`try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()`

EDIT 2:
Creating a new ViewController fixed it smh the one I used was bugged, couldn't find what caused the error

Comment: You have a two storyboard at the same time?

Comment: Your instantiated view controller seems to unrecognizable from the system side. Add following line of code to your vc: let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "AuthScreen", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp") as! YourViewControllerForSignUP

Comment: @Mannopson yes, one is my auth storyboard(login/signup/pw reset), the other is main app

Comment: Are you changed your code as suggested above?

Comment: @Mannopson I just woke up will try it later, I'll then reply if it worked or not

Comment: @Mannopson adding `as! SignUpViewController`didn't fix the error

Comment: @Mannopson The error may not be the switch of the view but the `FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()` itself

Comment: Look in your code where is defined `logOutAction:`. My guess is that the ViewController in your Storyboard has not the correct class (`UIViewController` instead of `YourViewControllerClassWhereIsDefinedLogOutAction`).

Comment: @Larme I already checked that. I might found the error, I tried the function on a different view and it worked, smh it just ain't working in this specific one, I will create a new one and that'll fix it

Comment: Found the mistake, the class wasn't part of the App but the WriteUITest, sorry for your time. I am so dumb sometimes :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Solved: the Class was part of WriteUITest and not the App itself.